# adding attribute to url for Summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [summernote](https://github.com/HackerWins/summernote) and I am having trouble adding attributes to Link.  How can I add `target="_blank" rel="nofollow"` to the inserted url?

I have found this line, somewhere on line 977:

```
 sLinkUrlWithProtocol = sLinkUrl.indexOf('://') !== -1 ? sLinkUrl : 'http://' + sLinkUrl;
```

I have tried adding +'target="_blank"' to the end.  The result was garbage, showing this:

```
http://sample.comtarget%3D%27_blank%27/
```

Comment: Try to change 982 line: `rng.insertNode($('<A target="_blank" id="linkAnchor">' + sLinkUrl + '</A>')[0]);`

Comment: I added this to the line but doesn't do anything.  This line is under an if condition for IE, I guess, and I am using chrome and firefox so this line then get passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My full (probably working) solution =] Lines 980 - 989

```
    //IE: createLink when range collapsed.
    if (agent.bMSIE && rng.isCollapsed()) {
      rng.insertNode($('<A target="_blank" id="linkAnchor">' + sLinkUrl + '</A>')[0]);
      var $anchor = $('#linkAnchor').removeAttr('id')
                                      .attr('href', sLinkUrlWithProtocol);
      rng = range.create($anchor[0], 0, $anchor[0], 1);
      rng.select();
    } else {
      document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,'<a target="_blank" href="'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'">'+sLinkUrl+'</a>');
    }
```

Comment: This does add target='_blank' but it replaces the highlighted text with the entered url.  So if I highlight a text, say 'testing' and entered 'google.com' in the url field, the result would be `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a>`.  I can't seem to find the variable that holds the selected text.

Comment: alright, this seems to work

`document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,'<a target="_blank" href="'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'">'+rng+'</a>');`