# Summernote - Add _blank or _self to links

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

There's a similar question [adding attribute to url for Summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662632/adding-attribute-to-url-for-summernote).

But it doesn't add the possibility of choosing target, it just sets it to blank.

Is there a way to add "target" to the link popup?

```
    //IE: createLink when range collapsed.
if (agent.bMSIE && rng.isCollapsed()) {
  rng.insertNode($('<A target="_blank" id="linkAnchor">' + sLinkUrl + '</A>')[0]);
  var $anchor = $('#linkAnchor').removeAttr('id')
                                  .attr('href', sLinkUrlWithProtocol);
  rng = range.create($anchor[0], 0, $anchor[0], 1);
  rng.select();
} else {
  document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,'<a target="_blank" href="'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'">'+sLinkUrl+'</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several hacks you need to do:

1)
In line 2112 (aprox) you'll find:

```
           '<div class="form-group">' +
                     '<label>' + lang.link.textToDisplay + '</label>' +
                     '<span class="note-link-text form-control input-xlarge uneditable-input" />' +
                   '</div>' +
```

Add the following code:

```
                   '<div class="form-group">' +
                     '<label>' + lang.link.target + '</label>' +
                     '<select class="note-link-target form-control col-md-5" id="link-target"><option value="_self">Same page</option><option value="_blank">New page</option></select>' +
                   '</div>' +
```

2) Line 1331 (aprox) cointains these var definitions:

```
  var $linkText = $linkDialog.find('.note-link-text'),
      $linkUrl = $linkDialog.find('.note-link-url'),
      $linkBtn = $linkDialog.find('.note-link-btn');
```

Add:

```
$linkTarget = $linkDialog.find('.note-link-target'),
```

3) Line 2357 (aprox) has the link definition:

```
    link: {
      link: 'Link',
      insert: 'Insert Link',
      unlink: 'Unlink',
      edit: 'Edit',
      textToDisplay: 'Text to display',
      url: 'To what URL should this link go?'
    },
```

Add

```
target: 'Target'
```

to the list

4) Finally: line 1011 (aprox) replace the code from the comment '//IE' to the end of the 'if'.

```
    //IE: createLink when range collapsed.
    var target = $("#link-target").val();
    if (agent.bMSIE && rng.isCollapsed()) {
      rng.insertNode($('<A target="'+target+'" id="linkAnchor">' + sLinkUrl + '</A>')[0]);
      var $anchor = $('#linkAnchor').removeAttr('id')
                                      .attr('href', sLinkUrlWithProtocol);
      rng = range.create($anchor[0], 0, $anchor[0], 1);
      rng.select();
    } else {
      document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,'<a target="'+target+'" href="'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'">'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'</a>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply modify the html being generated to include a dynamic target.

```
rng.insertNode($('<A target="' + mytarget + '" id="linkAnchor">' + sLinkUrl + '</A>')[0]);
```

and

```
document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,'<a target="' + mytarget + '" href="'+sLinkUrlWithProtocol+'">'+sLinkUrl+'</a>');
```

Comment: Did that. And also added the "mytarget" to the modal window code and the "link" attribute. 
But I don't know where the "mytarget" variable is passed to the parser function